# Como mudar estilo CSS da coluna de tabela ao passar o mouse?

Tags: html, css

Como alterar o estilo *CSS* (backgrounc-color) de uma coluna inteira ao passar o mouse, usando apenas *CSS*?

A tabela em questão é a seguinte:

```
<table class="un table">
    <caption>Título da tabela</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Coluna 1</th>
            <th>Coluna 2</th>
            <th>Coluna 3</th>
            <th>Coluna 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>L1 X C1</td>
            <td>L1 X C2</td>
            <td>L1 X C3</td>
            <td>L1 X C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>L2 X C1</td>
            <td>L2 X C2</td>
            <td>L2 X C3</td>
            <td>L2 X C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>L3 X C1</td>
            <td>L3 X C2</td>
            <td>L3 X C3</td>
            <td>L3 X C4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total C1</td>
            <td>Total C2</td>
            <td>Total C3</td>
            <td>Total C4</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

No caso, ao passar o mouse em cima de uma das colunas, alterar o background-color de toda a coluna, inclusive o cabeçalho e o rodapé.

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass/11175979#11175979

Comment: Infelizmente se utilizar <caption> também muda o fundo em parte dele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando apenas CSS, dá para fazer um fake utilizando o pseudo-elemento `after`, veja o exemplo:

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border:solid red;
  border-width    : 1px 2px 1px 1px;
}
table caption {
  background-color:#fff;  
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
  
}
td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table class="un table">
    <caption>Título da tabela</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Coluna 1</th>
            <th>Coluna 2</th>
            <th>Coluna 3</th>
            <th>Coluna 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>L1 X C1</td>
            <td>L1 X C2</td>
            <td>L1 X C3</td>
            <td>L1 X C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>L2 X C1</td>
            <td>L2 X C2</td>
            <td>L2 X C3</td>
            <td>L2 X C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>L3 X C1</td>
            <td>L3 X C2</td>
            <td>L3 X C3</td>
            <td>L3 X C4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total C1</td>
            <td>Total C2</td>
            <td>Total C3</td>
            <td>Total C4</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Fontes: [Simple CSS-Only Row and Column Highlighting](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/) e
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848840/cols-colgroups-and-css-hover-psuedoclass/11175979#11175979)

Comment: Boa solução, porém está "iluminando" o <CAPTION> também.

Comment: @EvertondaRosa basta colocar uma cor de fundo no `caption`, veja minha edição.

Comment: Excelente abfurlan. Muito obrigado. Esse código será de grande utilidade.

Comment: Há novamente um problema: se utilizo border-collapse: collapse na tabela, a borda direita fica cortada por causa do overflow: hidden.

Comment: @EvertondaRosa da para resolver aumentando um pouco a borda da direita, exemplo: `border:solid red;  border-width    : 1px 2px 1px 1px;`, veja a edição.